# Grunt Concat Não Unifica Arquivos

Tags: node.js, grunt, concatenação-de-string

Quero unificar meus arquivos css em um só, mas o grunt não unifica. Funciona perfeitamente para os javascript.

Segue:

```
concat: {
    options: {
        separator: '\n\n',
    },
    css: {
        src: [
            'dist/app/css/*.css'                
            , 'dist/app/lib/boostrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
            , 'dist/app/lib/boostrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
        ],
        dest: 'dist/app/css/all.css'
    },
    js: {
        src: [
           /* Uma grande lista de arquivos omitidos */
        ],
        dest: 'dist/app/js/all.js'
    }
},
/* código restante omitido, mas também funciona corretamente */
```

Nenhum erro é exibido no console.
Mesmo rodando o comando `grunt` ou `grunt concat:css`.

Comment: conseguiu resolver seu problema?